# Beamer ignores citecolor from hyperref

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, hyperref

How do I make *citation* links green in Beamer? It seems that Beamer ignores the hyperref option `citecolor`. I tried using the `linkcolor` option instead, but that affects all links (such as the link to the next slide, see example below). I want to change **only** the citation color.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks = true,
% linkcolor = green,
  citecolor = green
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
This is a great result~\cite{Paper}.
But this is a link to slide~\ref{Bib}.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Bibliography}\label{Bib}
\begin{thebibliography}{}
  \bibitem[Author, 1942]{Paper}
    Author. B.
    \newblock The great result.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Weird: `citecolor=green` works in `article`, but not in `Beamer`. Someone else might know a work around.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could redefine `\@cite` to locally change the link color:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks = true,
  linkcolor = red
}

\makeatletter
\let\@mycite\@cite
\def\@cite#1#2{{\hypersetup{linkcolor=green!60!black}[{#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}]}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
This is a great result~\cite{Paper}.
But this is a link to slide~\ref{Bib}.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Bibliography}\label{Bib}
\begin{thebibliography}{}
  \bibitem[Author, 1942]{Paper}
    Author. B.
    \newblock The great result.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The above solution did not work for me. But I was successful by putting the following line in the preamble:

```
\let\oldcite=\cite                                                              
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{.7,.7,.7}{\oldcite{#1}}}
```

Comment: This works for me, but it colors the brackets too -- any idea on a regex solution, or something?