# Citation colour with Beamer + Hyperref + Natbib

Tags: beamer, hyperref, color, natbib

I'm using `natbib` for citation with a custom bibstyle. I'm working on a presentation using LaTeX `beamer` and for some reason the citation marker doesn't have the colour that is specified to `hyperref`. The citation marker is black instead of green. I'll give you a MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  citecolor=green,
  linkcolor=red
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@ARTICLE{Bar2011,
  author = {F. Foo and F. Bar},
  title = {Foo and Bar},
  journal = {Journal of Foo},
  year = {2011},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {1--3}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[comma,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}
Dummy referefence to~\cite{Bar2011}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

For the purpose of the MWE I have selected the `plain` bibstyle, however, changing that to something else (including the custom style I want to use) doesn't affect the label colour.

Is there any patch for this problem?

Comment: I had the same problem recently. See the answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104290/beamer-ignores-citecolor-from-hyperref).

Comment: @MārisOzols you may have noticed that I specified that I'm using `natbib` which you do not.

Answer (score 6):

I do not remember where, but sometime ago, I found this workaround:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[comma,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=green,
    linkcolor=red,
    backref=true
}

\let\oldbibitem=\bibitem
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[2][]{\label{#2}\oldbibitem[#1]{#2}}
\let\oldcite=\cite
\renewcommand\cite[1]{\hypersetup{linkcolor=green} \hyperlink{#1}{\oldcite{#1}}}
\let\oldcitep=\citep
\renewcommand\citep[1]{\hypersetup{linkcolor=green}\hyperlink{#1}{\oldcitep{#1}}}
\let\oldciteauthor=\citeauthor
\renewcommand\citeauthor[1]{\hypersetup{linkcolor=green}\hyperlink{#1}{\oldciteauthor{#1}}} 


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
    @ARTICLE{Bar2011,
        author = {F. Foo and F. Bar},
        title = {Foo and Bar},
        journal = {Journal of Foo},
        year = {2011},
        volume = {1},
        pages = {1--3}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    Dummy referefence to~\cite{Bar2011}
    \bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The solution offered by samcarter did not quite work for me. But I was successful by putting the following lines into the preamble:

```
\let\oldcite=\cite                                                              
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{.7,.7,.7}{\oldcite{#1}}}
```