# Beamer citation footnote: Adding *note* to citation

Tags: beamer, citing

This is a [follow-up](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386707/38244) question (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/493496/38244) too for another follow-up question).

From the accepted [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/390575/38244), when I try to add *note* [not sure what the proper terminology is] to the citation (as in `\cite[page 0]{mybibitem}`), I observe that the *note* appears twice (see minimal working example below):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=numeric,citecounter=true,citetracker=true]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{myreferences.bib}
    @online{bad,
        author = {{Bad Man}},
        year = {1313},
        title = {Bad Title},
        url = {http://badurl.com/},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{myreferences.bib}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165016/38244
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=red,
    linkcolor=blue,
%   backref=true
}



\usepackage{algorithm}
\PassOptionsToPackage{noend}{algpseudocode}% comment out if want end's to show
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{algorithmicx}


\let\svthefootnote\thefootnote

\makeatletter
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29931/38244
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
{%  
    \ifciteseen{}{%
        \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \let\thefootnote\relax%
        \footnotetext{%
            \blx@anchor
            \mkbibbrackets{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
            \setunit{\addnbspace}
            \printnames{labelname}%
            \setunit{\labelnamepunct}
            \printfield[citetitle]{title}%
            \newunit%
            \printfield[]{year}%
        }%
        \let\thefootnote\svthefootnote%
    }%
    \autocite{\thefield{entrykey}}%
  }
{\addsemicolon\space}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother



\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{What I found}
    First time, \cite[page 99]{bad}   
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Again}
    Next time, \cite[page 1]{bad} only
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

Here are the screen-shots (see the duplication of the *note*s):
[image: page 1]
[image: page 2]

How can I get rid of the duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `prenote` and `postnote` parts, and perhaps the associated punctation, in your definition of `\cite` as the `\autocite` call will take care of these:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=numeric,citecounter=true,citetracker=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{myreferences.bib}
    @online{bad,
        author = {{Bad Man}},
        year = {1313},
        title = {Bad Title},
        url = {http://badurl.com/},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{myreferences.bib}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165016/38244
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=red,
    linkcolor=blue,
%   backref=true
}



\usepackage{algorithm}
\PassOptionsToPackage{noend}{algpseudocode}% comment out if want end's to show
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{algorithmicx}


\let\svthefootnote\thefootnote

\makeatletter
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29931/38244
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
{}%
{%
    \ifciteseen{}{%
        \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \let\thefootnote\relax%
        \footnotetext{%
            \blx@anchor
            \mkbibbrackets{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
            \setunit{\addnbspace}
            \printnames{labelname}%
            \setunit{\labelnamepunct}
            \printfield[citetitle]{title}%
            \newunit%
            \printfield[]{year}%
        }%
        \let\thefootnote\svthefootnote%
    }%
    \autocite{\thefield{entrykey}}%
  }
{}
{}
\makeatother



\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{What I found}
    First time, \cite[page 99]{bad}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Again}
    Next time, \cite[page 1]{bad} only
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I have also removed the `\addsemicolon\space`, but you might want to retain this, it is the punctuation between multiple citations in the same call of `\cite`: `\cite{one,two}`.

In your comments you asked for removing the year from the output in the footnote.  All you need to is remove the corresponding lines from the new `cite` command:

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
{}%
{%
    \ifciteseen{}{%
        \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \let\thefootnote\relax%
        \footnotetext{%
            \blx@anchor
            \mkbibbrackets{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
            \setunit{\addnbspace}
            \printnames{labelname}%
            \setunit{\labelnamepunct}
            \printfield[citetitle]{title}%
        }%
        \let\thefootnote\svthefootnote%
    }%
    \autocite{\thefield{entrykey}}%
  }
{}
{}
\makeatother
```

[image: yearless sample]

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but how can I remove the `year` field from the bibliography?

Comment: You can either delete the year line from the entry in the `bib` file, or you can dynamically delete this for all `@online` entries via `\DeclareSourcemap{\maps[datatype=bibtex]{\map{\pertype{online}\step[fieldset=year,null]}}}`

Comment: The second approach seems tangential to my head :-). Can we do something like deleting `\newunit%` and `\printfield[]{year}%`?

Comment: Yes, if you just want to remove it from that output of the citation command; but this won't affect the bibliography that you asked about.

Comment: OK, I mistyped the question... I wanted to remove the year from output of the citation command (so that year is not printed where the information on the cited entry is printed).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [answer](https://pastebin.com/46eZy1nP) from the user [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/user36296) (who is apparently suspended from this site):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=numeric,citecounter=true,citetracker=true]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{myreferences.bib}
    @online{bad,
        author = {{Bad Man}},
        year = {1313},
        title = {Bad Title},
        url = {http://badurl.com/},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{myreferences.bib}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165016/38244
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=red,
    linkcolor=blue,
%   backref=true
}



\usepackage{algorithm}
\PassOptionsToPackage{noend}{algpseudocode}% comment out if want end's to show
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{algorithmicx}


\let\svthefootnote\thefootnote

\makeatletter
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29931/38244
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
{%  
    \ifciteseen{}{%
        \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \let\thefootnote\relax%
        \footnotetext{%
            \blx@anchor
            \mkbibbrackets{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
            \setunit{\addnbspace}
            \printnames{labelname}%
            \setunit{\labelnamepunct}
            \printfield[citetitle]{title}%
            \newunit%
            \printfield[]{year}%
        }%
        \let\thefootnote\svthefootnote%
    }%
    \autocite{\thefield{entrykey}}%
  }
{}
{}
\makeatother



\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{What I found}
    First time, \cite[page 99]{bad}   
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Again}
    Next time, \cite[page 1]{bad} only
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```