# Multiple reference citation is not working with bibtex using natbib, citep and hyperlink in beamer

Tags: natbib, hyperlink

I use the beamer to write some teaching notes with .bib files. By some clues from 
[josephwright](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/114) 
and [user36296](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114082), I made some tests on my little example as follows:

```
    \documentclass{beamer}

    %\usepackage[comma,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
    \usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
    %\bibliographystyle{plain}

    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks,
        citecolor=green,
        linkcolor=red,
        backref=true
    }

    \let\oldbibitem=\bibitem
    \renewcommand{\bibitem}[2][]{\label{#2}\oldbibitem[#1]{#2}}
    \let\oldcite=\cite
    \renewcommand\cite[1]{\hyperlink{#1}{\oldcite{#1}}}
    \let\oldcitep=\citep
    \renewcommand\citep[1]{\hyperlink{#1}{\oldcitep{#1}}}
    \let\oldciteauthor=\citeauthor
    \renewcommand\citeauthor[1]{\hyperlink{#1}{\oldciteauthor{#1}}} 
    \newcommand{\newblock}{}

    \begin{document}

    \title{Multiple reference citation: natbib + citep + hyperlink}
    \frame{ \titlepage }

    \begin{frame}{only}
    \only<1>{\begin{block}{block 1}
    \citep{hastie2009elements}
    \end{block}}
    \only<2>{\begin{block}{block 2}
    \citep{hastie2009elements,james2013introduction}
    \end{block}}
    \only<3>{\begin{block}{block 3}
    \citep{hastie2009elements},\citep{james2013introduction}
    \end{block}}
    \end{frame}


    \begin{frame}%[allowframebreaks]
    %\tiny
    \frametitle{References}
    \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
    \bibliography{test}
    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

where the `test.bib` file contains two references

```
    @book{james2013introduction,
    title={An introduction to statistical learning: with applications in R},
    author={James, Gareth and Witten, Daniela and Hastie, Trevor and Tibshirani, Robert},
    year={2013},
    publisher={Springer},
    address={New York}
    }
    @Book{hastie2009elements,
    Title       = {The elements of statistical learning: Data mining, inference, and prediction},
    Author      = {Hastie, Trevor and Tibshirani, Robert and Friedman, Jerome},
    edition   = {2},
    Publisher   = {Springer},
    address      ={New York},
    Year        = {2009}
    }
```

It works well with the right hyperlink to the References page for the single citation (i.e., `\citep{hastie2009element}` or `\citep{james2013introduction}`).
However, clicking on the PDF with 
the multiple reference citation `\citep{hastie2009elements,james2013introduction}`
always leads to the title page! Any help?

Comment: Two comments: First, on my system (MacTeX2019 with all updates installed), I am unable to reproduce the issue you say you encounter, viz., jumping to the titlepage instead of the bibliography page when clicking on one of the citation call-outs. Which TeX distribution do you employ? Second, the code chunk in which you redefine `\bibitem`, `\cite`, etc shouldn't be (and isn't!) necessary if your TeX distribution is reasonably up to date.

Comment: Tks a lot for your comments!@Mico Maybe you are right that my MiKTeX is too old. While in fact according to [josephwright](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/114) website, someone there also encouter my problem, i.e., `It seems that this workaround does not work anymore. More precisely, all the citations are hyperlinked to the title page (as if the label is created there...). Maybe \renewcommand{\bibitem}[2][]{\label{#2}\beameroldbibitem[#1]{#2}} does not work as expected...`  by Halil Şen'comments there.