# biblatex style verbose, beamer and color in block

Tags: beamer, biblatex, color

I use `biblatex` with `citestyle=verbose` inside `beamer`.

With this style, the name of the author is automatically colored, and also the title. That is a nice feature ... except if you cite your a work inside a title of a beamer block: you can't read anything, because it becomes, with for example the Darmstadt theme, blue on blue.

See my minimal example following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usepackage[citestyle=verbose]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@book{Augustin,
    Author={Augustin},
    Title={La cité de Dieu}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{\cite{Augustin}}

blabla
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Any idea to disable this feature of coloring ?

Comment: notes : it's working with authortitle bibstyle, but I don't want to use it : I need a full reference

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104290/beamer-ignores-citecolor-from-hyperref

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123145/36296 you can work around this problem by defining your custom cite command to be used in the block title. Like this, you can keep the nice colouring feature for the rest of the presentation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usepackage[citestyle=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
    @book{Augustin,
        Author={Augustin},
        Title={La cite de Dieu}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\customcite}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}%
      \indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \printnames{labelname}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}%
   \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
   \newunit
   \printfield{year}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{block}{\customcite{Augustin}}
            blabla \cite{Augustin}
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
        \frametitle{References}
        \printbibliography
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, that work! just before sending the bounty, I will wait if other people have other solution...