# beamer citation style color and size

Tags: beamer, biblatex, renewcommand, parencite

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
```

In my slide file using beamer, using above package with `\parencite` shows (Roman 1984) style citation in the slide.

I want to make this citation with 10pt font size with `lightgray` color. Please let me know how to change size and font size! (I guess it is using `\renewcommand` stuff but I am not sure about it)

Comment: You could use the same technique as in @Ulrike's answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/351387/36296

Answer (score 0):

Just to show you how you can use @Ulrike's answer from the duplicate:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newcommand\mkbibcolor[2]{\textcolor{#1}{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont \mkbibparens{#2}}}  
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibcolor{lightgray}]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
text \parencite{knuth:ct} text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```