# Beamer, Citation coloring

Tags: beamer, biblatex, hyperref, color

I try to color the in-text citations in my beamer presentations. I use several citations per item, mostly via \parencite. To increase readability I want the references (including brackets) to be printed in grey. Unfortunately all the solutions and workarounds ([Citation colour with Beamer + Hyperref + Natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114082/citation-colour-with-beamer-hyperref-natbib), [Beamer: Biblatex biber, change color of citations globally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351379/beamer-biblatex-biber-change-color-of-citations-globally) and [Beamer ignores citecolor from hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104290/beamer-ignores-citecolor-from-hyperref])) won't do the trick. Either all the links (sections and subsections) are colored or nothing changes.

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[germanb]{babel}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[backend=biber, uniquename=false, maxbibnames=99, maxcitenames=2, citestyle=authoryear, bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{andothers = {{et\, al\adddot}},}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addslash}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{\usebibmacro{journal}  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}\iffieldundef{series}{}{\newunit    \printfield{series}\setunit{\addspace}}\usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}  \setunit{\addspace}\usebibmacro{issue+date}\setunit{\addcolon\space}\usebibmacro{issue}\newunit}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}%
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{pages}{#1}%
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{\printfield{volume}\setunit*{\adddot}\setunit*{\addnbthinspace}\printfield{number}\setunit{\addcomma\space}\printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\space}
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{\ifnameundef{editor}{}{\setunit{\addspace}\printnames[byeditor]{editor}\clearname{editor}\setunit{\addspace}\usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}\newunit}\usebibmacro{byeditorx}  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{byeditor ={\addspace\mkbibparens {Hrsg\adddot}\addcolon},}
\newbibmacro*{byeditor:in}{\ifnameundef{editor}{}{\printnames[editorin]{editor}\addspace\bibsentence    \mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{editorstrg}}\clearname{editor}\printunit{\addcolon\space}}}
\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}{\usebibmacro{in:}\usebibmacro{bybookauthor}\newunit\newblock\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}   \newunit\newblock\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}{\usebibmacro{in:}\usebibmacro{bybookauthor}\newunit\newblock\usebibmacro{byeditor:in}   \newunit\newblock\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}\newunit\newblock\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}{\usebibmacro{in:}\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}\newunit\newblock  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}{\usebibmacro{in:}\usebibmacro{byeditor:in}\setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}\newunit\newblock\usebibmacro{byeditor}}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{inproceedings}{\usebibmacro{in:}\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}\newunit\newblock  \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}\newunit\newblock\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}{\usebibmacro{in:}\usebibmacro{byeditor:in}  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}\newunit\newblock\usebibmacro{event+venue+date}\newunit\newblock   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}{}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{\mkbibparens{\ifinteger{#1}{\mkbibordedition{#1}~\bibstring{edition}}{#1\isdot}}}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\addbibresource{/home/tassilo/Dokumente/01-Literaturdatenbank/Masterfile/references.bib}
\usetheme{Malmoe}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\author{Vorname Nachname}
\date{30. Mai 2017}
\title{Titel}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@Book{bartolini-mair-1990,
  author =    {Bartolini, Stefano AND Mair, Peter},
  title =    {Identity, Competition and Electoral
                  Availability. The Stabilization of European
                  Electorates 1885-1985},
  publisher =    {Cambridge University Press},
  year =    1990,
  address =    {Cambridge},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{frame}{Outline}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}


\section{Einleitung}
\label{sec:orgheadline6}
\begin{frame}[label={sec:orgheadline1}]{Einleitung}
Text \cite{bartolini-mair-1990}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should put a *minimum* example: remove all the packages and stuff that are not directly related to the question. That way, it would be easy to somebody to test your example and came up with a solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could either set the colour for the hyperlinks with

```
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=green,
    linkcolor=black
}
```

(this will only colour the click-able part of the citation) or add the colour manually to the citation commands:

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}

\usepackage[backend=biber, uniquename=false, maxbibnames=99, maxcitenames=2, citestyle=authoryear, bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\color{red}\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkcolorbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd{\mkcolorbibparens}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \color{red}%
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \bibopenparen#1\bibcloseparen
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@Book{bartolini-mair-1990,
  author = {Bartolini, Stefano AND Mair, Peter},
  title = {Identity, Competition and Electoral Availability. The Stabilization of European Electorates 1885-1985},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  year =  1990,
  address = {Cambridge},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Text \cite{bartolini-mair-1990} text

Text \parencite{bartolini-mair-1990} text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! That's exactly the solution I'm looking for. However if I copy the code into org-mode (and add #+LATEX_HEADER: to each line) it produces an error and tells me I have a runaway argument.

Comment: @Tazzism Sorry, I have no idea about org-mode.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm really greatful for your solution. It might have to do with how org-mode processes org-File into tex.

Comment: is is possible to add parentheses around the year in the `cite` command?