# Modifying citation command

Tags: biblatex

I am using the code provided in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369710/beamer-citation-coloring) question regarding coloring citations.

The problem is that I don't know how to make (redefine) the `cite` command to add parentheses around the year

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple hack, defining a `colortextcite` command, based on `\textcite`:

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}

\usepackage[backend=biber, uniquename=false, maxbibnames=99, maxcitenames=2, citestyle=authoryear, bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\color{red}\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkcolorbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd{\mkcolorbibparens}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \color{red}%
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \bibopenparen#1\bibcloseparen
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@Book{bartolini-mair-1990,
  author = {Bartolini, Stefano AND Mair, Peter},
  title = {Identity, Competition and Electoral Availability. The Stabilization of European Electorates 1885-1985},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  year = 1990,
  address = {Cambridge},
}
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\colortextcite}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\textcite{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Text \cite{bartolini-mair-1990} text

Text \parencite{bartolini-mair-1990} text

Text \colortextcite{bartolini-mair-1990} text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i need to learn how to create my own command/macros...the problem is that i don't know where to start and i don't understand their syntax (e.g. in your hack i don't understand the purpose of `[1]` and `#1`

Comment: `[1]` is the number of arguments of the macro, and inside the definition of the macro, `#1` denotes this argument (which here is replaced by the biblatex key). This being said, you can find lots of tutorials on [tug.org](https://www.tug.org/interest.html#latextutorials).